# Connect to postgres database behind nginx reverse-proxy using docker containers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, postgresql, containers

I have set up a postgres database container and can connect and query it directly using its published port 5434.

***The goal is to deploy the test database later and access it via nginx reverse proxy.
I don't know what is the best way to connect to a deployed test database. Please advise.***

I have tried to connect to a postgres database via nginx reverse proxy using local containers.

**Using command:**

```
psql -h localhost -p 5435 -U postgres database_name_container_test
```

**Nginx shows error:**

```
reverse-proxy | 2021/10/29 20:06:57 [info] 32#32: *17 client 172.25.0.1:56630 connected to 0.0.0.0:5435
reverse-proxy | 2021/10/29 20:06:57 [error] 32#32: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server:
0.0.0.0:5435, upstream: "172.25.0.3:5434", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
stream {    
    upstream database_test {
        server postgres_test:5434;
    }
    server {
        listen 5435 so_keepalive=on;
        proxy_pass database_test;

    }
}
```

**test_db docker-compose:**

```
services:
  postgres_test:
    container_name: postgres_test
    image: postgis/postgis
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    volumes:
      - ./backup:/backup
      - ./postgres-init-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres-init-db.sh
      - postgres_test_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env.postgres
    networks:
      - common-network

volumes:
  postgres_test_data:

networks:
  common-network:
    external:
      name: common-network
```

**reverse-proxy docker-compose:**

```
networks:
  common-network: #name in this docker-compose file
    name: common-network # the actual name of the network

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.20.1
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 5435:5435
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    networks:
      - common-network
```

Additionally I checked postgres configuration files, they seem to be correct:

```
cat postgresql.conf | grep listen_addresses
listen_addresses = '*'


cat pg_hba.conf | grep host
host all all all md5
```

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to the Docker container by name, you should use the exposed port of a service, i.e. `5432`, as you are connecting directly to the guest:

```
        server postgres_test:5432;
```

On the other hand, the published port `5434` becomes present on the host, so you should be able to access the services this way too:

```
        server localhost:5434;
```

Which I do not recommend, as you should need to account the port mapping for the future administration (instead of just knowing the container name and a standard exposed port).